# Updating data with Hibernate and Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

A few days ago I started to develop a Spring Batch application, that queries database, processes objects and updates changes. For this purpose I use HibernateCursorReader and HibernateItemWriter, both are xml-configured. Read and process are working well, but update throws an exception or does nothing.

What is the "right" way to update modified data in a chunk-based job? Commit to writer? Open new session? Use DAO, that opens its own session?

Thx,
Flo

Comment: HibernateItemWriter should work OK, what is the error being thrown? could you post the batch XML definition and the writer code

Comment: @jhadesdev After reading the following blog article http://www.andersen-gott.com/2011/11/spring-batch-and-hibernate.html , I changed the job to use only HibernateItemWriter without a reader.